# Value of type UIview has no member text

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var userGuessTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UIView!


@IBAction func Guess(sender: AnyObject) {

    let diceRoll = String(arc4random_uniform(6))

    if diceRoll == userGuessTextField.text
    {
        resultLabel.text = "You are right"
    }
    else
    {
        resultLabel.text = "You are "
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Can anyone help me? Why I am getting this error as I am a beginner to iOS and learning this language.

Comment: your `resultLabel` is `UIView` not `UILabel` ... so this is not gonna work because UIView doesn't have any member `text` ... You have to use `UILabel`

Comment: Is the `resultLabel` outlet connected to an `UIView` or an `UILabel` ? .. It should be connected to an `UILabel` to make the `.text` work.

Comment: Well.... if you write `resultLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dummy.png"];` You will get `Value of type UIView has no member image`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please change...

```
@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UIView!
```

to

```
@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!
```

Comment: connected outlet of UIView??? you need label in storyboard ... just change in code not working

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Lion

Answer (score 2):

You are setting outlet like `@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UIView!`, It is type of `UIView`, so your `resultLabel` object is of `UIView` and it's not have property `text`

I think you should take outlet of `UILabel` instead of `UIView`.

So, drag a label in interface builder - ctrl + drag from it to class (in assistant editor) - and give outlet name.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/):

The `UIView` class defines a rectangular area on the screen and the interfaces for managing the content in that area.

... More sophisticated content can be presented by subclassing UIView and implementing the necessary drawing and event-handling code yourself. The UIKit framework also includes a set of standard subclasses that range from simple buttons to complex tables and can be used as-is. For example, **a `UILabel` object draws a text string** and a `UIImageView` object draws an image.

Remove the resultLabel from your storyboard/xib (delete the `UIView` and drag a new `UILabel` ) and from code change:

from:

`@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UIView!`

to

```
@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!
```

Then connect your new `UILabel` to the IBOutlet writed on code.